# Why doesn't my obstacle sprite appear on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the obstacle sprite, which are asteroids, to fall from the top of the screen to the bottom. I havent added any code to mess with the collisions of the asteroids, gravity, etc. because I can't even get the sprite to appear on the screen. Here is my code below (I tried using sprite classes but for me personally it made it a lot more confusing and difficult, so I chose not to.)

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint


def animation_state():
    global player_surface, player_index, player_rect
    

    player_index += 0.15
    if player_index >= len(player_right_walk):
        player_index = 0
    
    if LEFT == True:
        player_surface = player_left_walk[int(player_index)]
    elif RIGHT == True:
        player_surface = player_right_walk[int(player_index)]


    if LEFT == False and RIGHT == False:
        player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_right.png').convert_alpha()
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_left.png').convert_alpha()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_idle_right.png').convert_alpha()

    
    screen.blit(player_surface,player_rect)

def player_control():
    global LEFT, RIGHT
    player_velocity = 0
    player_gravity = 0
    

    player_gravity += 3
    player_rect.y += player_gravity
    if player_rect.bottom >= 500:
        player_rect.bottom = 500
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_velocity -= 6
        LEFT = True
        RIGHT = False
        if player_rect.x < -50:
            player_rect.x = 800
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_velocity += 6
        LEFT = False
        RIGHT = True
        if player_rect.x > 800:
            player_rect.x = -50

        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_velocity = 0
    
    
    player_rect.x += player_velocity

def display_score():
    current_time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000) - start_time
    score_surface = font.render('Score: ' + str(current_time),False,(64,64,64))
    score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center = (375, 30))
    screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)
    return current_time
   
def game_over_screen():
    player_stand = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_stand.png').convert_alpha()
    player_stand = pygame.transform.rotozoom(player_stand,0,4).convert_alpha()
    player_stand_rect = player_stand.get_rect(center = (375,280))

    game_name = font.render('Personal Project Game', False, (111,196,169))
    game_name_rect = game_name.get_rect(center = (375,100))
    
    game_message = font.render('Press Space to start',False, 'Black')
    game_message_rect = game_message.get_rect(center = (375, 500))

    screen.blit(background_surface,(0,0))
    screen.blit(player_stand,player_stand_rect)
    screen.blit(game_name,game_name_rect)
    screen.blit(game_message,game_message_rect)


def asteroid_animation_state():
    global asteroid_surface, asteroid_index, asteroid_rect

    asteroid_1 = pygame.image.load('graphics/asteroid_1.png').convert_alpha()
    asteroid_1 = pygame.transform.rotozoom(asteroid_1,-45,0)
    asteroid_2 = pygame.image.load('graphics/asteroid_2.png').convert_alpha()
    asteroid_2 = pygame.transform.rotozoom(asteroid_2,-45,0)

    asteroid_frames = [asteroid_1,asteroid_2]
    asteroid_index = 0
    asteroid_surface = asteroid_frames[asteroid_index]
    asteroid_rect = asteroid_surface.get_rect(midtop = (randint(0,751),-20))

    asteroid_index += 0.1
    if asteroid_index >= len(asteroid_frames):
        asteroid_index = 0
    
    asteroid_surface = asteroid_frames[int(asteroid_index)]

    asteroid_rect.bottom += 10
    if asteroid_rect.bottom >=600:
        asteroid_rect.bottom = -20
    
    screen.blit(asteroid_surface,asteroid_rect)




pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Escape Extinction')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750,563))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
LEFT = False
RIGHT = False
start_time  = 0
score = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('fonts/atari-font-full-version/atari_full.ttf', 25)

player_right_1 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_1_right.png').convert_alpha()
player_right_2 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_2_right.png').convert_alpha()
player_right_3 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_3_right.png').convert_alpha()
player_right_4 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_4_right.png').convert_alpha()

player_left_1 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_1_left.png').convert_alpha()
player_left_2 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_2_left.png').convert_alpha()
player_left_3 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_3_left.png').convert_alpha()
player_left_4 = pygame.image.load('graphics/dino_4_left.png').convert_alpha()

    
player_right_walk = [player_right_1,player_right_2,player_right_3,player_right_4]
player_left_walk = [player_left_1,player_left_2,player_left_3,player_left_4]

player_index = 0

#player_surface_right = player_right_walk[player_index]
#player_surface_left = player_left_walk[player_index]

player_surface = player_right_walk[player_index]
player_rect = player_surface.get_rect(midbottom = (375,300))




background_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/jumperbackground.png').convert()
ground_surface = pygame.image.load('graphics/grass.png').convert()

#obstacle_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
#pygame.time.set_timer(obstacle_timer,1400)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
        
            #if event.type == obstacle_timer:
             #   obstacle.add(Asteroid('asteroid'))

    screen.blit(background_surface,(0,0))
    screen.blit(ground_surface,(0,480))
     
    player_control()
    animation_state()
    display_score()
    asteroid_animation_state()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotozoom) on the `pygame.transform.rotozoom()` function :

> **rotozoom(surface, angle, scale) -> Surface**
> This is a combined scale and rotation transform. The resulting Surface will be a filtered 32-bit Surface. The scale argument is a floating point value that ***will be multiplied by the current resolution***. The angle argument is a floating point value that represents the counterclockwise degrees to rotate. A negative rotation angle will rotate clockwise.

So your image loading code is scaling the images by a factor of `0`.  So the resultant surface would have a zero size.

Probably you meant this to be `1.0`, which would leave them the original size.

```
asteroid_1 = pygame.image.load('graphics/asteroid_1.png').convert_alpha()
asteroid_1 = pygame.transform.rotozoom( asteroid_1, -45, 1.0 )
asteroid_2 = pygame.image.load('graphics/asteroid_2.png').convert_alpha()
asteroid_2 = pygame.transform.rotozoom( asteroid_2, -45, 1.0 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured this out before reading your comment, but I appreciate your help!